# How enable or disable Entity validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

I use Entity Framework 4 and MVC 2.
I Have an Address Entity, Contact, Company. 
There are a relation between Contact and Address and Company and Address.. A Contact can Have an Address and a Company can also have an address too.

I created a Partial View for Address.

```
<div class="editor">   
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressID) %>
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressID) %>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.CivicNumber) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CivicNumber)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CivicNumber)%>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="editor">      
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Street) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Street)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Street)%>
        </div>
    </div> ......
```

I Call this Partial view in my Contact and Company View with EditorFor.

In the Address Class, I had some validation.
 Example : The Civic Number is required.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Civic Number is Required")]
[DisplayName("Civic Number")]
public object CivicNumber { get; set; }
```

Is it possible to Active this validation only when I Call Address from Contact. In other words. If I Call the Address.ascx from Company View I Don't want any validation for Address Fields. If I Call the Address.ascx from Contact View, I  want the validation for Address Fields.

Hope someone will understand. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure but give it a shot.

In your partial view

```
<% bool outputValidation = this.ViewContext.Controller.ViewData.Model.GetType() == typeof(Contact) %>

<div class="editor">   
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressID) %>
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressID) %>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.CivicNumber) %>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CivicNumber)%>
        <%: outputValidation ? Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CivicNumber) : "" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

What you are doing is getting the Model of the parent view. Then just check it's type.